# Maximizing app window while persisting Menu bar on top

Tags: macos, mojave

I would like to maximize all my app windows, especially browser windows. But I don't want to cover up the Menu bar at the top of the screen.

Right now, when I maximize Google Chrome for instance, it will expand all the way and hide the Menu bar, but when I hover the mouse pointer to the top, the window will jump up and down to reveal/conceal the Menu bar. I find this to be super annoying.

**The first step of the dance routine**:

[image]

**The second step of the dance routine**:

[image]

And, as I move my mouse up/down the view will toggle. I just want the Menu bar to always remain visible, but for my app windows to be maximized. Is that so hard?

Comment: There is no toolbar at the top of the screen; however there is a menu bar!

Comment: ok thanks yes that sounds like better terminology

Comment: @user3439894 and I were wondering if you want to see your apps in a [dedicated space](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH25574) or just maximised. Can you please clarify?

Comment: To clarify things, when clicking the green button in the top left of a window it places the window in its own space but hides the menu bar... are you wanting the app window in its own space but still showing the menu bar or just filling up the Desktop with the window?

Answer (score 2):

I also found this annoying and I use the excellent [BetterTouchTool](https://folivora.ai) in two ways:

First, I defined an action that right clicking the maximize button will maximise windows rather than trigger fullscreen mode. Of course, you can set your own action or key combination instead or even override the green button entirely.

[image]

Second, I use [Window Snapping](https://docs.bettertouchtool.net/docs/window_snapping.html), which basically imitates the functionality in Microsoft Windows. When you drag a window into a corner or to the top of the screen it will either enlarge it to an area of the screen or maximize it, respectively.

[image]

Comment: This does not put the window in its own space nor does it actually answer the question that was asked!

Comment: @user3439894 Err - why not?? Both solutions will leave you with a maximised app window where the menubar is still visible. I see no mention of dedicated spaces in OP's question??

Comment: When clicking the green button in the top left of a window it places the window in its own space just like the first image in the OP. I read the question to be wanting this but with the menu bar still showing. If that is not what the OP wants, then sorry for misreading the situation.

Comment: @user3439894 Good point - let's go ahead and ask OP :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the free tool [Spectacle App](https://www.spectacleapp.com/) which allows to maximize (but no full-screen) the windows to use all available desktop space with following keyboard shortcut:

<kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>

The keyboard shortcuts are visible in the app menu and can be changed within the app if they interfere with your workflow.

[image]

Comment: This does not put the window in its own space nor does it actually answer the question that was asked!

Answer (score 0):

It's very easy to accomplish something very similar to what you are trying to do *without* resorting to any 3rd-party tools.

In macOS Mojave, the default action for the maximize button is to take an app window full-screen. Notice how the icon displays two triangles facing in diagonally opposite direction.

[image]

With an app window is in full-screen mode, the default behavior of macOS is to hide the Menu bar, and reveal it upon hover at the top.

You can press and holding the <kbd>Option</kbd> key while clicking on maximize button, to prevent the app window from going into full-screen mode. But this will only maximize the window to reveal all content (which may not necessarily be same as full maximizing).

---

As this is not what you want, you can achieve a very similar end-result **without** taking app window full-screen. To accomplish this, simply move the cursor to any of the four corners of the app window, until it turns into a double sided diagonal shaped arrow like one of these (depending on which corner you choose):

[image] or [image]

Now, with this cursor icon visible, press and hold the <kbd>Option</kbd> key, and double click to maximize the app window to cover the entire screen, *without* hiding the Menu bar (as shown):

[image]

To reap the full benefit of this approach (i.e. achieving full-screen mode like appearance *with* Menu bar visible), it is recommended to enable Dock auto hiding by going to System Preferences → Dock and check *Automatically hide and show the Dock*.

Comment: This does not put the window in its own space nor does it actually answer the question that was asked!

Comment: @user3439894 I agree. It's a workaround over the unavailable feature in macOS.

Comment: yeah if you double click the top frame of chrome, it will do the same thing as (green button + option)...but I don't see how holding option and using one of the four corners is different seems to have same effect as holding option key and using green button

Comment: @AlexanderMills There's a difference. Holding the Option key while pressing the green button may not always maximize the window to cover the "whole" available screen. It only maximizes to fit the content.